# Invoke different functions using dictionary values

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I have two classes:

- One is called `Stock()` and the `averageopen`, `averagehigh`, `averagelow` are methods of `Stock()` class.
- And one is `AppGUI()` is the `Tkinter` file.

**Problem:** I want to invoke each individual average methods from the `Stock()` class in my `StartPage` class

```
Class StartPage():
......
......

    # calculate check boxes button
    self.button_calculate = tk.Button(self, 
    text="Calculate",command=self.average)
    self.button_calculate.pack()
    self.button_calculate.place(x=180, y=300)

    self.Google = Stock()        
    button_dict = {`'Average Open': self.Google.averageopen, 
    'Average High': self.Google.averagehigh, 
    'Average Low': self.Google.averagelow`}
```

How do I call the value from the `button_dict`? 
When do that, it returns `PY_VAR0` but I want to just invoke the function itself?

Comment: Have you tried `button_dict['Average Open'](arguments)`?

Answer (score 0):

You call it by accessing the dictionary value and passing in any parameters like you would with any other function:

```
button_dict['Average Open'](parameter, parameter, ...)
```

If it's returning `PY_VAR0`, that's unrelated to how you call it. The function will return the same thing no matter how it is called.

Typically, when you see `PY_VAR0`, that means you are using or returning an *instance* of `StringVar` when you mean to be using the *value*.

The following code will print "PY_VAR0"

```
foo = tk.StringVar(value="this is foo")
print(foo)
```

The following will print "this is foo":

```
foo = tk.StringVar(value="this is foo")
print(foo.get())

foo =
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the eval() function to dynamically call functions contained in the dictionary. Here's a simple example:

```
class Stock(object):
    def averageopen(self):
        return True

s = Stock()
the_dict = {}
the_dict.update({'Average Open':s.averageopen})

#see that we're about to execute
print 's.' + the_dict['Average Open'].__name__ + '()'

#now execute it
print eval('s.' + the_dict['Average Open'].__name__ + '()')
```

Running this code will return the value from the function reference stored in the dict: True

You can concatenate parameters into the string by adding them between the '()'. Iterate as necessary.

Comment: why use `eval`? It's completely unnecessary. This is a bit like driving to the grocery store by taking your car apart, carrying it in boxes to the store, and then rebuilding the car in the parking lot.

Comment: Realize that functions in python are objects (like everything else)- you don't need to build a string of the thing and then evaluate it, you can just get the function object and call it by using `obj()`. In fact, you can allow any object to kinda behave like a function by defining the `__call__()` magic method.